# Redirect based on user post count

Tags: posts, count

I'm at a loss..

I wanna check the current users post count. If the post count is 1, the user should be redirected. I have tested the following code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (empty($the_user_id)) {
        $the_user_id = $current_user->ID;
    }
$user_post_count = count_user_posts( $the_user_id );

  if ( is_page('butiktest') && $user_post_count == 1 ) {

        wp_redirect( 'enhytte', 301 ); 

    exit;

    }

}
```

However, the above code will redirect no matter the amount of posts.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: After pointing out my syntax error was a missing "=", it is still not working.

EDIT 2: The code is in theory working, however, once a post is added, the `user_post_count` is not updated, and stays at the previous value.

EDIT3: count_user_posts only count published posts, how do I check for 'pending' and 'draft'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

    function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    global $post;

    $current_user = $post->post_author;

    if(!empty($current_user)){
    $user_post_count = (int) count_user_posts( $current_user );

       if ( is_page('butiktest') && $user_post_count == 1 ) {

            wp_redirect( 'enhytte', 301 ); 

            exit;

      }
   }        
   }
```

authorized user: `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();`

Comment: Haha, of course. Completely forgot that. However, it is still not working for some reason. If I change it to >= 1, the redirect is done all the time regardless of posts. == never redirects.. I am checking for a custom post type, should this type be specified somewhere maybe?

Comment: `is_page('butiktest')` works correctly? Check out: `var_dump(is_page('butiktest'), $user_post_count);`

Comment: Not sure if I did it correctly, but on the frontpage, the values are: bool(false) string(1) "2", this is on a user with 1 post. Once I click the button, where the redirection should happen, the values become: bool(true) string(1) "2". I was expecting an integer and not a string?

Comment: you $user_post_count is 2 and that you check == 1.

Comment: If I change the value to 2, it comes with a PHP error in some of the theme files. Should it not be an integer and not a string?

Comment: Updated code about a mistake - do not understand

Comment: edited code errors should not be

Comment: OK, the error only came if I had the dump part in my php file. However, it seems the post count is not working. I created a new user on the site, which displayed: bool(true) string(1) "0". After making a post, the value is still 0.

Comment: updated answe code

Comment: I've got an addition to the post. user_post_count only check for posts that are published, how to I check for several values like 'pending', 'draft'?

Comment: use function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_many_users_posts

Comment: Oh I do not understand, you'd better ask a separate question

Answer (score 1):

You simply have a typo, should be:

```
$user_post_count == 1
```

Comment: What is your answer differs from mine?

Comment: Submitted it as I checked the solution when the answers were still 0, @Beyond55, please mark TrubinE's answer as correct.

Comment: Plus for honesty